# Does Cloudera Mountable HDFS provide deduplicaion

Tags: hadoop, storage, fuse, hdfs, cloudera

Looking at running a HDFS based storage cluster, and looking at a simple method of using the Mountable HDFS system through the Cloudera release.

The first question I ask is will this provide automatic deduplication of data?

The second question I ask if deduplication will be done, when all user delete files that contain the certain deduplicated block, does it then actually delete the block from storage or just the index/reference for that user?

Lastly, would this method include the Rainstor compression methods?

Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

No, HDFS does not include data deduplication.

The architecture is mainly focused on optimally use sequential write/read patterns, so it is pretty much against deduplication as every deduplication approach I am aware of introduces a certain amount of random IO pattern.